# How to find out fonts' native word space?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography

I need to set up average word space of M/4 in InDesign where M = 10pt. That is equal to 2.5pt. InDesign lets me adjust word spacing in terms of percentage of fonts' native word spacing.

However, I have no idea how to get fonts' native word spacing figure, therefore I can't figure out what % of that I need to get 2.5 points. How/where can I read fonts' default word spacing from?

Comment: Exact measuring could easily be done with scripting, however, I don't quite understand your question. What exactly do you mean by word space? Could you explain?

Comment: I am interested default pixel or relative-em distance between words in a piece of text, that font sets.

Comment: "InDesign lets me adjust word spacing in terms of percentage of fonts' native word spacing" is correct, but the *physical* distance depends on the font size in use. I see no mention of that. You cannot set the Word Spacing to make a space 2.5 pts **in all sizes** – it will only work for one specific size.

Answer (score 2):

Word spacing is a proportional measure. You may have to approximate it by experiment. Proportionality *may* have a benefit working with percentages.

If you set MMM (three solid glyphs) and M M (three glyphs enclosing two letter spaces and a word space), the difference of the distance between them is a word space.

Measuring carefully will/may give you the current (native?) word space.

You can reduce your measurement error by either:
1.) increasing the font point size and/or by
2.) increasing the number of characters in the experiment to ten, or twenty, say.

Answer (score 1):

For an exact figure: Open the font in a font editor (there are free ones and free trial versions) and check the width of the space character (U+0020). It is measured in units per em and em is equal to the point size.